# The difference in Class.where(id: '1234') and Class.find_by id: '1234'

Tags: ruby, mongodb, ruby-on-rails-4

I've just come across a subtle difference between `.where` and `.find_by` apparently `.where` returns only the `_id` of an object I am looking for whereas `.find_by` returns a hash. Could someone explain the difference between the two methods in Rails 4 and mongodb?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read the [documentation on the ActiveRecord Query Interface](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html).

> ## 1 Retrieving Objects from the Database
>
> To retrieve objects from the
>   database, Active Record provides several finder methods. Each finder
>   method allows you to pass arguments into it to perform certain queries
>   on your database without writing raw SQL.
>
> The methods are:
>
> ...snip...
>
> - where
>
> All of the above methods return an instance of `ActiveRecord::Relation`.

So the result of calling `Class.where(...)` is a collection of objects.

And:

> #### 1.1.5 find_by
>
> The find_by method finds the **first record matching** some conditions.
>   For example:
>
> ```
> Client.find_by first_name: 'Lifo'
> # => #<Client id: 1, first_name: "Lifo">   Client.find_by first_name: 'Jon'
> # => nil
> ```

(emphasis mine)

So the result of calling `Class.find_by(...)` is the first found object.

Comment: So `.where(id: 1234).first == .find_by id: 1234`?

Comment: Correct! Also note you do this on a Class rather than on an object (as in the question title)

Comment: In the end I should use `.where` if I want to perform an action on objects that meet the criteria I pass as a parameter and `.find_by` if I am looking for one object that meets the criterion.